# Is there a way to write to the microphone input device in OSX

Tags: macos, audio, microphone

How does the microphone device work in OSX, can you pipe audio to it in order to make OSX think you are talking?

Comment: You should think about your question and word it more carefully. The way I read it is that you would like to play a sound *out* of your microphone which is obviously not possible. The fact that you'd expect the say command to include the microphone as a choice reinforces this. I'd guess what you are asking is if you can create a virtual audio input that *acts* like a microphone to apps that would expect a microphone but instead get the audio from another source.

Comment: so.. you got was I was asking just fine... thanks for the help?

Comment: I agree with @jaket: Your question is not clear

Comment: I didn't get the answer just fine, I just read between the lines. Anyway, since you have soundflower you can route the audio output back to an audio input if that is your goal.